# Changing duplicated coordinate values by adding a decimal place R

Tags: r, duplicates, coordinates

I have UTM coordinate values from GPS collared leopards, and my analysis gets messed up if there are any points that are identical. What I want to do is add a 1 to the end of the decimal string to make each value unique.

What I have:

```
> View(coords)
> coords
          X       Y
1  623190.9 4980021
2  618876.6 4980729
3  618522.7 4980896
4  618522.7 4980096
5  618522.7 4980096
6  622674.1 4976161
```

I want something like this, or something that will make each number unique (doesn't have to be a +1)

```
> coords
          X       Y
1  623190.9 4980021
2  618876.6 4980729
3  618522.7 4980896
4  618522.71 4980096.1
5  618522.72 4977148.2
6  622674.1 4976161
```

Ive looked at existing questions and got this to work for a simulated data set, but not for values with more than 1 duplicated value.

```
DF <- data.frame(A=c(5,5,6,6,7,7), B=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3))

>View(DF)
  A B
1 5 1
2 5 1
3 6 2
4 6 2
5 7 2
6 7 3

DF <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(DF, list(DF$A, DF$B)), 
  function(x) {
  x$A <- x$A + seq(0, by=0.1, length.out=nrow(x))
  x$B <- x$B + seq(0, by=0.1, length.out=nrow(x))
  x
}))

>View(DF
         A    B
5.1.1  5.0  1.0
5.1.2  5.1  1.1
6.2.3  6.0  2.0
6.2.4  6.1  2.1
7.2    7.0  2.0
7.3    7.0  3.0
```

The'2s' in column B don't continue to add a decimal place when there are more than 2. I also had a problem accomplishing this when the number was more than 4 digits (i.e. XXXXX vs XX) There's probably a better way to do this, but I would love help on adding these decimals and possibly altering them in the original data frame which has 12 columns of various data.

Comment: I'd just add a tiny bit of random noise to everything. `coords$Y = coords$Y + rnorm(nrow(coords), mean = 0, sd = 0.01)` will jitter each point a tiny bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to use `make.unique`

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, function(x) as.numeric(make.unique(as.character(x))))
DF
#    A   B
#1 5.0 1.0
#2 5.1 1.1
#3 6.0 2.0
#4 6.1 2.1
#5 7.0 2.2
#6 7.1 3.0
```

Comment: @DavidHeit You can remove the `as.numeric`  `lapply(DF, function(x) make.unique(as.character(x)))$A
[1] "55555555"   "55555555.1" "66666666"   "66666666.1" "66666666.2" "66666666.3"`

Comment: That solves my initial problem. My coordinate values are 8 digit numbers, any idea why it wouldn't work for them? Once the values are greater than 8 digits I am noticing that the values do not change

Comment: @DavidHeit  As I already commented, just remove the `as.numeric` and it worked for me